# Determining if a binary addition has overflow

Tags: arithmetic, binary

that if
Im trying figure out how to determine whether a binary addition has overflow. My understanding is that if the cin is not equal to cout then there is overflow.

So that in that case for the following example:
01110101 + 10111011 = 00110000.
Has overflow. Is that correct.

Comment: What are cin and cout?

Comment: carry in and carry out

Answer (score 0):

You have overflow if there is carry out, regardless of whether there is carry in or not?  If you have just two bits, $10+10$ overflows without a carry in.  $10+10+1$(carry in) overflows even though carry in and carry out are equal.